# set column of pandas.DataFrame object

Tags: python, pandas

Ideally, I want to be able something like:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df = pandas.DataFrame(index=range(5), columns=cols)
df.get_column(cols[0]) = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What is the pythonic/pandonic way to do this?

Edit: I know that I can access the column 'A' by `df.A`, but in general I do not know what the column names are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to store what columns a DataFrame has separately.

You can find out what columns exist in a pandas DataFrame by accessing the `DataFrame.columns` variable.

To access the Series attached to a particular column, you can use the getitem method of the DataFrame `[]`

Tiny example:

```
col = df.columns[0]
df[col] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is particularly straightforward.

```
df[cols[0]] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```